# How to edit the placeholder installation filepath in an exe?

Tags: windows-10, installation, automation

I have this piece of software with a simple 1-2-3 installation. It sits on a shared drive at my workplace, in a folder we use as a software repository for deploying to user's workstations. Oddly enough, the default installation is set to a specific user's C drive, rather than the C drive local to wherever the installer is. This has gone unnoticed because it puts a shortcut to the program on their desktop!

How can I modify this behaviour so that the exe (which was probably set to this user's pc because he downloaded it first) always draws an install path relevant to where it's being installed?

The program is VSPlayer v7.2.0 if you're interested

Comment: Copying the installer to your local machine before running it?

Comment: This doesn't work, it always defaults to the specific machine. It can be changed manually, but my desire is to have it automated to a one-click install.

Comment: From what I can see, this doesn't need to be installed at all.  Install it once, copy the VSPlayer folder and uninstall it.  Your "installation" looks like it only needs a shortcut.